# React-leaflet does not work using create-react-app and react 16.8.4

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm trying to get a basic example of react-leaflet 2.2.1 to work with the latest react release, 16.8.4.  However, the leaflet map does not display correctly.

I used create-react-app to create a new project, then modified the App.jsx to include a component that is identical to the codepen example given for react-leaflet. The only change is to the containing div where I specified the height & width.

The map tiles do not render within the div and instead end up in somewhat random positions.
[image]

The entire app code  in https://github.com/sknutsonsf/agdex/tree/master/src

This looks like some kind of compatibility issue with the new react version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, adding

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

solved my problem